# BioPython: Processing raw RNAseq reads (quality filtering and trimming)

Tags: python, biopython

I have a raw, unaligned fastq.gz file that I am trying to preprocess using Biopython before alignment. I would ultimately like to remove low quality reads, trim polyA tails, trim adapters using fuzzy matching, and finally remove reads that do not satisfy a length requirement after all said preprocessing. It would also be neat to specify how many reads satisfy the filtering criteria at each step. I have been playing around with this Biopython script but have had little success.

```
# coding: utf-8

'''
process_reads.py
March 31, 2016

Convert FQ files to unaligned and tagged BAMs
I: compressed FQ
O: compressed, filtered FQ
'''

import gzip, statistics
from Bio import SeqIO, pairwise2

def get_stats(reads):
    sizes = [len(r) for r in reads]
    print("Total reads: %i" % len(sizes))
    print("Mean read length: %i" % statistics.mean(sizes))
    print("Max. read length: %i" % max(sizes))
    print("Min. read length: %i" % min(sizes))

def quality_filter(reads, qual):
    return (r for r in reads if min(r.letter_annotations["phred_quality"]) >= qual)

def trim_polyA(records, numA, minLen):
    for record in records:
        if len(record) < minLen: continue
        record = record.seq.split("A"*numA, 1)[0]
        yield record

def _remove_adaptor(seq, region, right_side=True):
    if right_side:
        try:
            pos = seq.find(region)
        # handle Biopython SeqRecords
        except AttributeError:
            pos = seq.seq.find(region)
        return seq[:pos]
    else:
        try:
            pos = seq.rfind(region)
        # handle Biopython SeqRecords
        except AttributeError:
            pos = seq.seq.rfind(region)
        return seq[pos+len(region):]

def trim_adaptor(seq, adaptor, num_errors, right_side=True):
    gap_char = '-'
    exact_pos = str(seq).find(adaptor)
    if exact_pos >= 0:
        seq_region = str(seq[exact_pos:exact_pos+len(adaptor)])
        adapt_region = adaptor
    else:
        seq_a, adaptor_a, score, start, end = pairwise2.align.localms(str(seq),
                                                                      str(adaptor),
                                                                      5.0, -4.0, -9.0, -0.5,
                                                                      one_alignment_only=True,
                                                                      gap_char=gap_char)[0]
        adapt_region = adaptor_a[start:end]
        seq_region = seq_a[start:end]
    matches = sum((1 if s == adapt_region[i] else 0) for i, s in enumerate(seq_region))
    # too many errors -- no trimming
    if (len(adaptor) - matches) > num_errors:
        return seq
    # remove the adaptor sequence and return the result
    else:
        return _remove_adaptor(seq, seq_region.replace(gap_char, ""),
                right_side)

def process_reads(fq, qual, adapt, numA, minLen):
    with gzip.open(fq) as f:
        rawReads = SeqIO.parse(f, "fastq")
        # get_stats(rawReads) # When I run this, everything downstream fails..
        qualFil = quality_filter(rawReads, qual) # I think this work fine.
        trimmedPoly = trim_polyA(qualFil, numA, minLen)
        trimmedAdap = trim_adaptor(trimmedPoly, adapt, 2)

        # count = SeqIO.write(trimmedAdap, "good_quality.fastq", "fastq")
        # print(count)

# TEST PROCESSING
fq = "test/TAAGGCGA_2.fq.gz"
process_reads(fq, qual=50, adapt="AAGCAGTGGTATCAACGCAGAGTGAATGGG", numA=6, minLen=20)
```

I believe the quality filter and polyA trimming works correctly but I cannot seem to get the adapters to cut. I have also written a function called `get_stats` that is supposed to return the average length and total reads. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You will probably get a better response if you show the community what you have tried (your code) within your question. Having said that, do you need to use Biopython? There are many tools out there that will already do many of the items you would like. I would start with looking into Fastx (http://hannonlab.cshl.edu/fastx_toolkit/commandline.html). You need to be mildly comfy with the command line, but they have many of the tools you are looking for. You can view the fastq file characteristics pre/post processing with FastQC (http://www.bioinformatics.babraham.ac.uk/projects/fastqc/).

Comment: Also, if you are married to Biopython, perhaps you can share what your output/error is with your get_stats function.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder that `right_side` is always set to `True`. So your `_remove_adaptor` method will only try to remove the adapter from the right side:

```
...
if right_side:
        try:
            pos = seq.find(region)
        # handle Biopython SeqRecords
        except AttributeError:
            pos = seq.seq.find(region)
        return seq[:pos]
```

But if you cut away the polyA from the right (keeping the left part of the sequence), will you still have an adaptor sequence on the right? My guess is that you want to cleave the adaptor from the left side.

Some example reads would be helpful.